# Wrong photo count

Tags: storage

My iPad mini says I have 1701 photos. I deleted all except maybe a hundred. Ipad still says I have 1701 photos. Where they at. Tried everything. Checked forums and they have same problem. What good is ICloud if they want store data and photos because I need storage. But it says I have 5 Gigabytes free. Help

Answer (score 1):

Your question has a few parts. I'll go through one by one.

> My iPad mini says I have 1701 photos. I deleted all except maybe a hundred. Ipad still says I have 1701 photos.

I presume you don't see these photos anywhere. Meaning if you go to Photos, they aren't there, and that you're referencing the count in Preferences > General > About. In this case, have you tried rebooting your device. Are the photos taking up space, or is the count just wrong?

> What good is ICloud if they want store data and photos because I need storage. But it says I have 5 Gigabytes free.

iCloud is primarily a syncing platform. Unless you opt to "optimize device storage" for the Beta Photo Library syncing, you won't get any benefits where you save space on your device. iCloud storage starts at 5GB, you may need to buy more. I have a 20GB plan and optimize my storage. My local photo library is smaller than my cloud photo library.

Comment: Count is wrong and there saying I need more storage in ICloud but my ICloud says I have a full free 5 gigabytes. They say ICloud won't store till I get more storage space or illiminate photos ,data etc. but I have 5 free gigabytes in ICloud. So I'm thinking the wrong amount of photos is the problem. At one time there probably was 1701 photos but we deleted most of them. Help

Comment: Ok, first check what awesomebing1 said.

Comment: So far nothing has worked. Still showing more photos than I have. Deleted album not showing pictures. Says my photos are using 6.8 gigabytes . Have less than 100. My husbands ipad is storing 775 photos in ICloud with plenty of storage. Something's not adding up. Help

Comment: Rebooting didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If your iPad mini shows these photos, and it is on iOS 8, this is why.
In iOS 8, they removed deleting photos. Now, your photos are stored in a album called "Recently Deleted".
To delete these photos:

- Go to Photos
- Click on Albums on the toolbar on the bottom
- Click on "Recently Deleted"
- Click "Delete All".

Comment: No photos in delete photo album

Comment: @TimothyGravely are you on iOS 8?